# How to generate random numbers when given the value of a probability density function?

Tags: random, numbers, distribution, probability

When given a set of values deriving from a probability density `function f`, like this

```
{f(X1),f(X2)... f(Xn)}
```

But we don't know the exactly form of `f`,only we know is that the probability density function is a generalized `Gaussian distribution`.

Is it possible to generate the random numbers `Xi` if `Xi` belongs to a range `[-3,3]`?

Comment: Post it on http://math.stackexchange.com/, unless you want it implemented in a specific programming language (in which case, please add what you have so far).

Comment: Are the X's a random sample, or equally spaced, or something different? Are they ordered?

Comment: I am doing some research in Image Processing，X is the value of noise I want to add to each pixel.Now I have the probability of the noise (f(Xi)) at each pixel and I order them according to the location of pixel (by row).As a result, there is a vector of probability of noise consistent with the pixel like {f(X1),f(X2)... f(Xn)}.  For example,X2 is the noise I want to add to the pixel located at (1,2),and f(X2）is the probability of this noise. Now I want to get f and X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way that I can see is this. Assuming that you have have large number of points {f(X1),--,f(Xn)}, plot them as distribution and fit a generalized Gaussian distribution curve through them. After this, you can use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) to generate further numbers from the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you for answering.But would you mind explaining how to curve them? I don't know how to set the X and Y coordinates and I want to implement it in matlab.

Comment: And here is the details of my question:X is the value of noise I want to add to each pixel.Now I have the probability of the noise (f(Xi)) at each pixel and I order them according to the location of pixel (by row).As a result, there is a vector of probability of noise consistent with the pixel like {f(X1),f(X2)... f(Xn)}. For example,X2 is the noise I want to add to the pixel located at (1,2),and f(X2）is the probability of this noise. I don't know how to get f and X according to the data I got.

Comment: Perhaps I may not understand technical details of your problem. But I can suggest you to use [least square fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares). This method is built-in in many softwares, for example 'gnuplot'. This would give you the curve which you need. After that you can use that curve to use in rejection sampling.

Comment: If you think that answer is useful, you may accept it by clicking that symbol near my answer.